# Latest supported CUDA version of Quadro 2000

Tags: cuda, version, gpu, nvidia, caffe

I need to run caffe on my GPU, but can not really find out what CUDA version my card actually supports. Running `nvidia-smi` just returns me `Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error`.

I have run the Nvidia bug report script `nvidia-bug-report.sh`, which outputs me a long log file where I cannot really see, what is wrong (would post it, if it was not the company's GPU).

What is the latest CUDA version my Quadro 2000 supports?

Comment: Best I can [find out](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-legacy-gpus) Quadro 2000 has compute capability 2.1, and you should therefore be able to use any CUDA version you like, up to and including CUDA 7.5, which is the latest shipping version. If I had to guess, your installation of CUDA may be damaged or incomplete, or there is a mix of files from multiple CUDA versions on your machine. I don't think questions about such configuration issues (close to impossible to diagnose remotely) are a good fit for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer and the link! I am working on the messed up configuration. Thanks for the hints as well!